# SiteCatalyst/Omniture Reporting REST API Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, rest, adobe-analytics

I've created a C# .NET client for interfacing with Adobe's SiteCatalyst/Omniture/Reporting 1.4 REST API (lord knows why they have to have so many names for the same thing) that exposes 100% of the functionality supported by the API and I'd like to publish it as a public NuGet package but I'm having issues with authentication.

I've done everything stated in their documentation (including setting up the app, et al) for authentication, stated here - https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/en_US/documentation/authentication/auth-client-credentials#concept_5190CB12025F4B29947AB2CF13435C9C - and tried every way I know to make the authentication request as they describe and always receive back an error saying I'm not sending the grant_type.  I've tried sending it as a query string parameter, header, URL encoded POST, JSON POST and every possible combination of the 4.  All of them give back the same error.

I also attempted using Fiddler to capture the request while using the curl statement listed in their documentation:

```
$ curl -i -v "https://api.omniture.com/token" -u 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID:YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this using Windows curl, it just blows up saying it can't verify the SSL certificate.

If someone could just show me what the request looks like for a successful authentication (headers, body, et al - although you can strip out the credentials) I can finish the NuGet package and have it out there for everyone to use to effortlessly interface with Adobe's Reporting API in .NET.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

-Ben

Comment: stupid question from me..did you do steps 1-3 to setup/obtain valid  id/secret creds? Did you replace `YOUR_CLIENT_ID:YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET` with real values in the request

Comment: Also for your testing vs. ssl cert issue, you could try [ignoring ssl authentication](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60750/does-curl-have-a-no-check-certificate-option-like-wget) for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

as a test a while back I used this HTML form to do this step in the OA2 handshake.

```
 <FORM action="https://api.omniture.com/token" method="post">
<P>
<LABEL for="grant_type">grant_type: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code"><BR>
<LABEL for="code">code: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="code" value="a77911ad9d0adf28f215577d7f05cda52fae8721"><BR>
<LABEL for="client_id">client_id: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="client_id" value="com.cdegroot.OA2.test1"><BR>
<LABEL for="client_secret">client_secret: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="client_secret" value="4169edfc847e77cfb35b"><BR>
<LABEL for="redirect_uri">redirect_uri: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="redirect_uri" value="http://localhost:9099"><BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
</P>
```

This should give you some pointers into how it works.

Thanks C>